# Cron expression to run after 30 minutes past hour

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I would like to schedule a job using Quartz to run 30 minutes past the hour. For example I want the job to run at 00:30, 1:30, 2:30 and so on.

Can you guys help me to get the correct cron expression?

Comment: The lack of effort shown to solve this problem yourself is impressive.

Comment: @MattBall dude `man crontab` is a lot of chareters to type. Its much easier to got to stackoverflow.

Comment: Guys, I was trying some other options and stuck with an interpretation that for a quartz scheduler cron expression is HH MM  .. instead the actual expression skeleton has seconds in the first place - SS MM HH .....   It took a while for me to get round this, but your funny comments aren't appreciated. I feel sorry for you guys.

Answer (score 16):

Simple enough

```
30 * * * *
```

Every 30th minute of every hour, every day of the month, every month, every day of the week. From wikipedia

```
# *    *    *    *    *  [command to execute]
# ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
# │    │    │    │    │
# │    │    │    │    │
# │    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names)
# │    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
# │    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

For quartz, the cron expression introduces more fields (7 total), the first being `seconds` and the last being `years` (but optional). You can see those [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

You need

```
* 30 * * * * [*]
```

Comment: everyday of the month already includes every day of the week.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yeah, I'm just explaining every position in the expression.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I tried your answer and the job is running for every 30 seconds. So I corrected it as - 0 30 * * * ? and it running as expected. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @Sirish Ah yes, it seems the quartz cron expressions are different than the normal ones. There are 7 positions, the first being `seconds`.

Comment: while the question sucks and is poor - it still comes up in search engines when researching for my own means - so still a great answer which told me exactly what I needed